# Deserializing an array of objects: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String[]

Tags: c#, json, .net

Can't access objects inside the array using JSON.Net

```
public class VoskReturnArray
{
  public string[] result { get; set; }
  public string text { get; set; }
}
    
var voskArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<VoskReturnArray>(rec.Result());

Console.WriteLine(voskArray.text); // Works fine
Console.WriteLine(voskArray.result); // Throws an exception
```

Tried with `<List<VoskReturnArray>>`, but then `text` won't show up.

What am I missing here?

Data:

```
{
  "result" : [{
      "conf" : 0.228337,
      "end" : 0.141508,
      "start" : 0.060000,
      "word" : "one"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 0.390000,
      "start" : 0.141508,
      "word" : "hundred"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 1.080000,
      "start" : 0.390000,
      "word" : "employees"
    }],
  "text" : "one hundred employees that's where it is you know they had the same problems are those five employees companies but they have the money to pay to fix them"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data shows `result` as an array of objects, while your `result` property in `VoskReturnArray` model is an array of string. It should be instead an array of a model type for those objects. So rather than:

```
public string[] result { get; set; }
```

You'd want something like:

```
public ResultItem[] result { get; set; }

...

public class ResultItem
{
    public decimal conf { get; set; }
    public decimal end { get; set; }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Great, but then how do I access those items? `voskArray.result[ResultItem].conf` doesn't work

Comment: It would be by index, usually in a loop where you check length first. To get first item (if exists): voskArray.result[0].conf

Comment: Unfortunately this returns just the first item, and not other items... `voskArray.result[1] will return out of index`

Comment: It's just standard .NET / C# at this point. `result` is an array of items. If that's unfamiliar I'd suggest looking for some tutorials on working with lists and arrays....

Comment: Actually it's not: `voskArray.result.GetType()` is `Program+ResultItem[]`. Not an array for sure.

Comment: That is indeed how .NET shows an array type in a class called `Program`.